# NoSQL Workbench - cannot commit table to dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a single table design in NoSQL Workbench and when I try to push the table to dynamodb I get this error message - **Could not commit to DynamoDB as table creation failed: ResourceInUseException: Table already exists:**.

I can confirm that the table is not there in dynamodb as of now, but the same table name was pushed multiple times and then deleted from dynamodb, would that be causing this error.

Comment: Are you certain you are checking the same region and account to confirm the table does not exist?  Confirm the NoSql workbench is using the correct credentials and that you are confirming the tables existence in the same account via some other method (via the console, AWS cli, etc)

Comment: @SethGeoghegan, I am 100% sure the table does not exist in the cloud. I removed the saved credentials and re-added them. I can see the table pushed, but now I get a different error - Failed to put 10 items to DynamoDB, Put succeeded for 0 items. Any idea, on how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Hard to say without reviewing the code you're trying to execute.  I suggest posting a new question with a code sample and error message.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan there is no code here. The table is created in NoSQl Workbench and the data is added directly there as well and after that I click the Commit to DyanamoDB button to push the table and the data. I have done this before and it worked, not sure what the issue is now.